# Cartodb Issues Regarding Toolbars

Tags: carto, toolbar

For some reason, the Cartodb software I'm using has no toolbar one the top left of the screen (the one with Add Element, etc.), and no toolbar on the bottom of the screen, where you can edit your map as well.  This is the case with any computer I work on with it.  Obviously, I can't continue with my project until I get this resolved.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Have you clicked "Visualize" in the upper left to get to create a map that is publishable? Without clicking on this (or doing the "New Map" from the dashboard), you are in a sandbox to explore the data.

Comment: Oops, upper right for the "Visualize" button, I mean

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that you are logged in into your CartoDB Account when you want to edit the map?

Because the appearance of the website (obviously) is, beside the missing toolbars, almost the same irrespective of whether you are logged in or view a published map.